# What is the correct chain rule for composite matrix functions?

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I present two versions of chain rule for composite matrix functions. To me, their statements are similar, however the results seem different.

From [Convex optimization and Euclidean Geometry book, Appendix A, page 7 of the document](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Edattorro/matrixcalc.pdf)

> 1. Given dimensioanlly comaptible matrix valued functions of matrix variable $f(\mathbf{X})$ and $g(\mathbf{X})$
>
> $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Delta_X \ g(f(\mathbf{X})^T)=\Delta_X \ f^T \ \Delta_X \ g$

Now, from the [Matrix Cookbook, page 15 of the document](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf),

> Let $\mathbf{U} = f(\mathbf{X})$, the goal is to find the derivative of the
> function $g(\mathbf{U})$ with respect to $\mathbf{X}$:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \frac{\partial g(f(\mathbf{X}))}{\partial X_{ij}}= Tr ((\frac{\partial g(\mathbf{U})}{\partial \mathbf{U}})^T \frac{\partial g(\mathbf{U})}{\partial X_{ij}})$

Now I understand that the second result gives only one element in the derivative matrix whereas the first equation is the entire derivative matrix. However, I can't see a trivial relation between the first and the second equation. Are they two equal?